# Swipe sensitivity in Ionic Slidebox + Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, cordova, scroll, user-experience, ionic-framework

I have scrollable content in each slide of an Ionic slide-box.

Everything worked perfectly, great user experience until I updated my Galaxy S5 from 4.4.2 to 4.4.4 this morning. Now the UX is an absolute nightmare. Scrollable content inside a slidebox is very difficult to work with. Side to side swiping sensitivity is super super high and prevents vertical scrolling unless absolutely perfectly vertical.

Tap-hold gestures are also really difficult to engage (again due to the side to side swipe sensitivity).

I have noticed this on my wife's Nexus 5 as well (which has always been running 4.4.4).

I am going to need to find a solution to this ASAP, since my Galaxy S5 is my primary demo device and it is a total train-wreck to work with now.

I recently updated to Ionic beta13, no change.  As in, a complete app UX fail, an embarrassment to have out in the wild.

I also uninstalled the Chrome update that came with Android 4.4.4 (37->35) in the hopes that the WebView would be downgraded to a previous version, no luck.

I'm wondering if there is something specific about my HTML setup, or what else I could provide to get at the issue.   I'm surprised I haven't seen more activity on this issue, because it is making my previously smooth app completely useless.  It leads me to believe that it is an isolated problem, but I don't know where to start.

Attached is an HTML template where this is happening to me.  Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

```
<ion-view title="LOVE.">
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button ng-if="activeSearchSlide == 2" class="button no-animation button-icon icon ion-ios7-arrow-back" style="-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" ng-click="clearSearch()">
    </button>   
</ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button no-animation button-icon icon ion-ios7-gear" style="-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); float: left;" on-tap="gotoSettings()" on-hold="holdMe()">
    </button>
    <button class="button no-animation button-icon icon ion-ios7-paperplane" style="-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" on-tap="sendFeedback()" on-hold="holdMe()">
    </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-content has-header="true" >  
    <ion-slide-box does-continue="false" auto-play="false" active-slide="activeSearchSlide" on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)">

        <ion-slide>
            <div>

                <label class="tagLabel" on-tap="clickTag()" on-hold="tagMenu($index, tag)" ng-repeat="tag in templates.categories track by $index" style="{{tag.checked | myTagStyle}}"> 
                    <p>{{tag.name}}<span ng-show="!tag.active">*</span><span class="searchCount">{{tag.bundleCount}}</span></p>
                </label>

                <form ng-submit="addTag(newTagText)">
                    <div>
                    <div style="border-left: none; border-top: none; border-bottom: none; border-right: 40px solid #f8f8f8">
                        <input type="text" id="inputText" ng-model="newTagText" placeholder="new tag category...">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <div ng-if="!somethingSelected" >
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p style="font-size:45pt;color:#DDD;">
            ???
            </p>
            </div>   
            <div>
                <div ng-repeat="tag in templates.categories track by $index" ng-show="tag.checked" class="check-element animate-show" >
                        <label class="tagLabel" on-tap="clickTag()" on-hold="tagMenu($index, tag)" style="{{tag.checked | myTagStyle}}">                            
                            <p>{{tag.name}}<span ng-show="!tag.active">*</span><span class="searchCount">{{tag.bundleCount}}</span></p>
                        </label>
                        <label class="tagLabel" on-tap="clickSubTag($parent)" on-hold="subTagMenu($index, item)" ng-repeat="item in tag.items track by $index" style="{{item.checked | myTagletStyle}}" >

                            <p><span style='display:inline-block;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>{{item.name}}<span ng-show="!item.active">*</span><span class="searchCount">{{item.bundleCount}}</span></p>
                        </label>
                    <form ng-submit="addSubTag()">
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" class="subtagTextInput" id="inputText" placeholder="new {{tag.name}} taglet..." ng-model="inputText">
                            </div> 
                        </div>    
                    </form>
                    <br/>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px;">

                        <h1>{{searchString}}</h1>

                        <div ng-repeat="bundle in searchResults track by $index | orderBy:attributes.timestamp:reverse">
                            <div on-tap="viewBundle($index)" on-hold="openBundleModal($index, bundle)" style="background-image: url('{{bundle.firstThumb}}');" class="item {{bundle.attributes.tagged | paintUntagged}}">
                                <div class="bundleCount"><p>{{bundle.URLcount}}</p></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-content>
<div>
    <button ng-if="locked && overLimit && onSearchPage" class="button button-energized inAppPurchase" ng-click="unlockApp()">{{searchLimit}}/{{totalBundles}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you update us if you found something new regarding this issue? Thanks! :)

Comment: Sadly this is still an open issue.  There is still a lot of back and forth about the way that Android handles "touchcancel", but nobody has gotten to the bottom of it yet.  I still have open issues on Ionic's issue tracker...

Comment: I should specify... the side swipe sensitivity was adjusted in response to my issue.  The tap-hold functionality is still broken.  If you are still having issues, please chime in here:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2373

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm having trouble with Ionic Swipe Cards not being swipeable on Android 4.1.x and 4.4.x. I'm using Ionic 1.0.0 beta 11 and Angular 1.2.6. Which version of Ionic and Angular are you using?

Comment: I have the same problem. When I use two finger down greatly work. But one finger is not sliding down.